# how to pass the filename as variable to a awk command from a shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

in my shell script i have the following line

```
PO_list=$(awk -v col="$1" -F";" '!seen[$col]++ {print $col}' test.csv)
```

which generates a list with the values from column "col" which came from "$1" from file test.csv.
it might be possible to have several files in same location and for this would need to loop among them with a for sentence. For this I have to replace the filename test.csv with a variable, $i for example, which is the index from the list of files.

trying to fulfill my request, I was modifying my line with

```
PO_list=$(awk -v col="$1" -F";" '!seen[$col]++ {print $col}' $j)
```

unfortunately, i receive the error message:

> awk: cannot open test.csv (No such file or directory)

Can anyone tell me why this error occur and how can I solve it, please?

Thank you,

Comment: are you running the script inside the same directory as test.csv?

Comment: Try modifying your script to say `ls "$j"` above your assignment line. Does that clarify the problem? By the way - always quote your shell variables (use `"$j"`, not `$j`) unless you have a specific goal in mind by leaving them unquoted and fully understand all the nuances and caveats of doing so.

Comment: @elrobe: indeed, this was my mistake. the test.csv file is not in same folder as my shell script. I modified the path and now it is working fine. thanks for opening my eyes.

Comment: it happens to me all the time. glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

As you commented in your previous question, you are calling it with

```
abc$ ./test.sh 2
```

So you just need to add another parameter when you call it:

```
abc$ ./test.sh 2 "test.csv"
```

and the script can be like this:

```bash
PO_list=$(awk -v col="$1" -F";" '!seen[$col]++ {print $col}' "$2")
#                                                            ^^^^
```

Whenever you want to use other parameters, remember they are positional. Hence, the first one is `$1`, second is `$2` and so on.

In case the file happens to be in another directory, you can replace `./test.sh 2 "test.csv"` by something like `./test.sh 2 "/full/path/of/test.csv"` or whatever relative path you may need.